# How to set constraint deferred in oracle with command C# to insert, update

Tags: c#, oracle

I use but error

and want DEFERRED to insert data, this set CONSTRAINTS  still run oracle

dangnhap.con in name connection

```
{
    string contrains = @"SET CONSTRAINTS system.fk_nvien_cnhanh_macn  DEFERRED;";
    //SET CONSTRAINTS system.Ma  DEFERRED;";
    dangnhap.cmd = new OleDbCommand(contrains, dangnhap.con);
    dangnhap.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. More precise, detailed and formatted question is needed to understand your issue. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Try `string contrains = @"{CALL SET CONSTRAINTS system.fk_nvien_cnhanh_macn DEFERRED}";` You must not include `;` in the command text.

Comment: Did you define your constraint in `SYSTEM` schema? You should not do this, create your own schema for this.